# How to incrementally create an sparse matrix on python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, bigdata

I am creating a co-occurring matrix, which is of size 1M by 1M integer numbers. 
After the matrix is created, the only operation I will do on it is to get top N values per each row (or column. as it is a symmetric matrix).

I have to create matrix as sparse to be able to fit it in memory. I read input data from a big file, and update co-occurance of two indexes (row, col) incrementally.

The sample code for Sparse dok_matrix specifies that I should declare the size of matrix before hand. I know the upper boundary for my matrix (1m by 1m), but in reality it might has less than that. 
Do I have to specify the size beforehand, or can i just create it incrementally?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
S = dok_matrix((5, 5), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        S[i, j] = i + j    # Update element
```

Comment: If you only need to extract the top value from each row, do you really need a matrix at all?

Comment: I will extract the top N values from each row of the final created co-occurrence matrix. i.e. while creating the matrix, for each element I read from the input file, I increment the value at co-occurance matrix at (row_i, col_j).

Comment: Could you use a dictionary instead, with (row,col) as the key?

Comment: @scott, exactly, I was going to do that, but I thought scipy library explicitly made for handling sparse matrices should be faster maybe ?!

Comment: The `dok` is a dictionary subclass.  But your `S[I,j]=...` has overhead and is considerably slower than a comparable plain `dict` `d[(I,j)]=....`.

Comment: Short answer - `dok` format does have a `resize` method.

Answer (score 2):

A SO question from a couple of days ago, [creating sparse matrix of unknown size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820079/creating-sparse-matrix-of-unknown-size),  talks about creating a sparse matrix from data read from a file.  There the OP wanted to use `lil` format; I recommended building the input arrays for a `coo` format.

In other SO questions I've found that adding values to a plain dictionary is faster than adding them to a `dok` matrix - even though a `dok` is a dictionary subclass.  There's quite a bit of overhead in the `dok` indexing method.  In some cases, I suggested building a dict with a tuple key, and using `update` to add the values to a defined `dok`.  But I suspect in your case the `coo` route is better.

`dok` and `lil` are the best formats for incremental construction, but neither is that great compared to python list and dict methods.

As for the `top N values` of each row, I recall exploring that, but back some time, so can't pull up a good SO question offhand.  You probably want a row oriented format such as `lil` or `csr`.

As for the question - 'do you need to specify the size on creation'.  Yes. Because a sparse matrix, regardless of format, only stores nonzero values, there's little harm in creating a matrix that is too large.

I can't think of anything in a `dok` or `coo` format matrix that hinges on the `shape` - at least not in terms of data storage or creation. `lil` and `csr` will have some extra values.  If you really need to explore this, read up on how values are stored, and play with small matrices.

==================

It looks like all the code for the `dok` format is Python in

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dok.py

Scanning that file, I see that `dok` does have a `resize` method

```
d.resize?
Signature: d.resize(shape)
Docstring:
Resize the matrix in-place to dimensions given by 'shape'.

Any non-zero elements that lie outside the new shape are removed.
File:      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dok.py
Type:      method
```

So if you want to initialize the matrix to `1M x 1M` and resize to `100 x 100` you can do so - it will step through all the keys to make sure there aren't any outside the new range.  So it isn't cheap, even though the main action is to change the shape parameter.

```
    newM, newN = shape
    M, N = self.shape
    if newM < M or newN < N:
        # Remove all elements outside new dimensions
        for (i, j) in list(self.keys()):
            if i >= newM or j >= newN:
                del self[i, j]
    self._shape = shape
```

If you know for sure that there aren't any keys that fall outside the new shape, you could change `_shape` directly.  The other sparse formats don't have a `resize` method.

```
In [31]: d=sparse.dok_matrix((10,10),int)

In [32]: d
Out[32]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>

In [33]: d.resize((5,5))

In [34]: d
Out[34]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>

In [35]: d._shape=(9,9)

In [36]: d
Out[36]: 
<9x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

See also:

[Why are lil_matrix and dok_matrix so slow compared to common dict of dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770906/why-are-lil-matrix-and-dok-matrix-so-slow-compared-to-common-dict-of-dicts)

[Get top-n items of every row in a scipy sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135927/get-top-n-items-of-every-row-in-a-scipy-sparse-matrix)